# Execute laravel route from a Artisan console command

Tags: php, class, laravel, laravel-5

how to execute a route request and get response from artisan console command class?

I have tried method suggested by others, which does not work as expected.

```
$request = Request::create('/', 'GET');
.
.
.
$response =  $route->run($request);
```

[using laravel 5]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$router = new Illuminate\Routing\Router(new Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher);

$request = Illuminate\Http\Request::create('', 'GET');

$router->dispatch($request);
```

From your code above I think you're confusing a route and the router. A route just contains information about how a single URI should be handled. The router itself compiles all your routes and determines the correct route to dispatch the request to.